# Convert RSS feed to JSON in java

Tags: java, json, rss

Is there any `api` or something to convert `RSS` feed to `Json`?
I used the api [rss2json api](http://rss2json.com/) with `restTemplate`, it's working fine when you map it with an `entity` but this one doesn't support multiple requests as it's gets overloaded plus there is no documentation for it or support so if the `api` goes down so is my app and I couldn't find something similar besides the `rome` plugin that converts to an object. I want direct conversion to Json.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by direct conversion to JSON, but you could simply use [org.json](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json) to convert XML String to JSON String:

```
String xml = ..
JSONObject jObject = XML.toJSONObject(xml);
String json = jObject.toString();
```

More discussion here: [Converting xml to json using jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15051973/converting-xml-to-json-using-jackson)

Answer (score 0):

I finished by using `Rome` plugin and built my own `JSon` structure step by step. no better solution so far.